# Skip a line in the body of an email

Tags: powershell

I have a script that sends mails when there are data table surcharges.

For that, I created a function that looks at the tables and sends an email for the broken tables :

```
$(
OverloadTable -Variable $PcaDos -Num 0 -Table PcaDos 
OverloadTable -Variable $PcaMal -Num 1 -Table PcaMal
OverloadTable -Variable $PcaRdv -Num 2 -Table PcaRdv
OverloadTable -Variable $Pc2Tpt -Num 3 -Table Pc2Tpt
OverloadTable -Variable $Pc2Dti -Num 4 -Table Pc2Dti
OverloadTable -Variable $Pc2His -Num 5 -Table Pc2His
OverloadTable -Variable $PcaLigFact -Num 6 -Table PcaLigFact
) | Foreach-Object { $EMAILBODY += $_ + "`r`n"}

#sending mail with the $EMAILBODY variable as the body
```

For example, if the table PcaDos and Pc2Dti are broken, the variable $EMAILBODY returns:

> The PcaDos table is overloaded
>
> The Pc2Dti table is overloaded

In the variable, there is a line break but in the body of the email, this line break is no longer there. Here is the example of the email sent :

> The PcaDos table is overloaded The Pc2Dti table is overloaded

I tried several things but nothing works like [Environment]::NewLine or even HTML with < br >

Is there a way to do this or not?

Comment: probably how you are using that variable. For example, `$EMAILBODY` is an array of strings, not a multiline string. Therefore, if the input for however you're sending the body doesn't do the conversion for you, PowerShell will probably do it. So, how are you sending it?

Comment: I send the mail by first informing the SMTP server then by declaring the subjects of the mail. Finally, I send the body like this : 

`$emailMessage = $EMAILBODY
$SMTPClient.Send($emailMessage)`

Comment: Try quoting it.